# PHP no image display from directory

Tags: php

When I run the PHP file, the image is not show, instead just the `alt`attribute value shown which is `14.JPG` .  The page source is also accurate and the image is also exist in that folder.

[image: page source]

Note - there are also some echo statements before this code. they are for other purposes.

Do I need to use headers also when displaying image this way?

```
$dir = "C:/xampp/htdocs/PHP";
$file = "14.JPG";

if ( file_exists($dir) == false ){
    echo 'Directory \''. $dir. '\' not found!';
}
else{
    echo '<img src="'. $dir. '/'. $file. '" alt="'. $file. '"/>';
}
```

Comment: You are giving wrong directory it should be **http://localhost/PHP**

Comment: @OwaisArain I changed to your suggestion. But then shows this - Directory 'localhost/PHP' not found!

Comment: check your URL put HTTP:// before localhost  and check that your image is in HTTP://localhost/php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You apply wrong approach please use relative url  make uploads folder in your PHP folder

```
$dir = "uploads/";
        $file = "14.JPG";

        if ( file_exists($dir) == false ){
            echo $dir .'not found!';
        }
        else{
            echo '<img src="'. $dir. '/'. $file. '" alt="'. $file. '"/>';
        }
```

Comment: Sir, I created uploads folder inside C:/xampp/htdocs/PHP folder. Then I copied 14.JPG into that folder. I also made $dir = "uploads". Now it works!!! Thanks. But explain me, why any of the paths (even told by other commentators for my post) do not work? What happens if I want to show 14.JPG if it includes in PHP folder (not in uploads folder)?

Comment: All commentators also right but not explain in details  php work with relative path  like if you access your php code with `htttp://localhost/php ` then your relative path start with your `xampp/htdocs/php` as root `/` after that write your relative path

Answer (score 4):

The problem is you're getting the file path mixed up with the URL. The file path is `C:/xampp/htdocs/PHP` and the URL is `http://localhost/PHP`. You need to use the URL when setting links to file and images. Your image source should be `http://localhost/PHP/14.JPG` but you've set it to `C:/xampp/htdocs/PHP/14.JPG`. Change it and it'll work for you.

Comment: Sir, when I changed to URL, output shows this Directory 'http://localhost/PHP' not found!

Comment: And you've got the `http://` at the front? If so then what URL are you browsing to?

Comment: Yes sir, I added it. But it didn't work. Only the solution suggested by @abhayendra worked for me!!!!! But I also want to know if it is mandatory to make a uploads folder inside my PHP folder???

Comment: No, it's not. You probably have `localhost` pointing directly to the PHP folder, though I'm not sure why. But in that case you can probably just use `http://localhost/14.JPG` to view the image.

Answer (score 0):

**Change This**

```
 $dir = "C:/xampp/htdocs/PHP";
```

**To This**

```
 $dir = "PHP/";
```

Comment: Sir, I maked your change. But now it shows - Directory 'PHP/' not found!